# Effect of velocity with a shift in coordinate axis

Tags: coordinate-systems, velocity

I am facing a problem dealing with velocity when coordinate axis (origin) is shifted. Could someone please explain me how the velocity changes if the coordinate axis is shifted. For ex: I have a velocity vector or $3\hat{i}+3\hat{j}$ and then origin is shifted to $2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}$. Now does the velocity changes to $1\hat{j}$? or is it something else?

Comment: If the both the coordinate systems are stationary wrt each other then velocity cannot be different

Comment: I think the confusion here is between translation and rotation. If you move the origin, the velocity vector doesn't alter its orientation. If you rotate the frame of reference the vector changes the orientation, without changing modulus; this type of transformation is part of the *group of rotations* $\text{SO}(3)$. You kind of transformation seems just a translation

Answer (score 0):

Unless tho origin has any velocity the velocity will remain same